# Is there a "follow me" Roomba/Create that works like a BEAMBot?

Tags: control, irobot-create, roomba

The diagram below shows an old BEAMBot strategy:

[image: Block diagram of IR based following circuit]

Is there code or an example using this method? I would rather avoid OpenCV, ultrasonic, GPS etc. I just want the Roomba wheels to react as I go straight, turn left or right. Finally, I could add a front wheel on a servo and try having the Roomba turn with me.

Also has anybody added big, all terrain wheels to a Roomba to replace the originals?

Comment: Do you mean like a _[Phototrope BEAMBot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_robotics#Types)_?

Answer (score 1):

The Roomba already does something very close to this: when it returns to its charging dock, it aligns itself with an IR signal coming from the top of the dock.  The procedure is more sophisticated, but the basics are the same.

According to [this PDF of the iRobot Roomba 500 Open Interface](http://irobot.lv/uploaded_files/File/iRobot_Roomba_500_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), there is a way to read the "infrared character" from the left, right, and omni sensors.  So you would need a device that could send an IR character (in Roomba's format) to the vehicle, and your code would detect and react to it.

Comment: For the device, you can get one of the iRobot virtual walls. It has a halo and beam, but you can block either with copper tape or similar.